# Multi-Language Orchard site with fixed backend language?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, orchardcms

I'm looking for a way to force Orchard to use a fixed language for the backend, while still being able to use the CulturePicker for the frontend.

Any hint would be highly appreciated - being my first project with Orchard I don't really know where to start - except ugly hacking...

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Seems like overkill given that you can just switch cultures before you navigate to the dashboard...

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. If I'm in the frontend of a foreign language, which I maybe don't even understand and I click the "Edit" link to copy and paste some content delivered from a 3rd party I'd like to understand the backend. This is especially true once the customers employees want to start editing content on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement your own `ICultureSelector`.

You need to check if user is on admin screen first. If so, return the default site culture, otherwise return null (this way the next culture selector, in your case the one from CulturePicker, should kick in).

Example:

```
    public class AdminCultureSelector : ICultureSelector {
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;

    public AdminCultureSelector(IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor) {
        _workContextAccessor = workContextAccessor;
    }

    public CultureSelectorResult GetCulture(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        string currentCultureName = _workContextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentSite.SiteCulture;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentCultureName) && AdminFilter.IsApplied(context.Request.RequestContext)) {
            return new CultureSelectorResult { Priority = 1000, CultureName = currentCultureName };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just built my first Orchard module and it works like a charm. I had a feeling it couldn't be so hard once you know where to start. I really love Orchard's extensibility it's so clean compared to other systems - the really hard thing seems to be getting to know all the anchor points ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear that! It is extremely extensible, indeed. Almost every piece of the default Orchard functionality can be easily overridden/extended without touching the core. The hardest part is to pinpoint the interface to implement, though (we'll have all those documented some day:)